# How should I set up a Maven/Groovy project in STS?

Tags: maven, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a project that uses some Java and some Groovy, and it's all built with Maven.  We use the GMaven plugin to compile the Groovy.  I've been using Eclipse and have got fed up with the "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle" message that indicates Eclipse is incapable of doing what my command-line does (I've tried adding the ignore/execute config to fix it, but it never works properly), so I've switched to Spring Tool Suite, which claims to have full Groovy support.  How should I set it all up?  So far I've had exactly the same experience as with regular Eclipse, but given that SpringSource are responsible for Groovy, I figure there must be a way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this thread?

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130130-Working-with-Mavenized-Grails-projects-in-GGTS-3-1-0-*Updated-for-3-1-0-release*/page2

For grails projects, you do not need to use gmaven or the groovy-eclipse-compiler.  You must be using the 3.1.0 STS (which is not actually released yet, but you can get this

You also must be using Grails 2.1.1.

You can secretly get a 3.1.0 release build by going to this download page:

http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts

Instead of clicking on the links, copy them and substitute 3.1.0 for 3.0.0.

Comment: I hadn't seen that thread, thanks, but sadly we're not using Grails.  It still seems like a surprising amount of effort to get this stuff working in Eclipse - my colleagues who use IntelliJ have no problems with Groovy and Maven at all - and I'm still looking for a seamless way to do it.

Comment: Sorry...misread your question.  I had Grails on the brain having just implemented that feature.  Getting this to work in a pure Groovy project is much, much easier.  From the STS extensions page on the dashboard, select "Groovy-Eclipse Configurator for M2Eclipse".  Install it and your lifecycle errors will go away.\

Comment: Sadly I already have that, it doesn't seem to do anything.  Do I need to turn it on in some way?

Comment: OK. Then it is possible that your project requires extra lifecycle mapping configurators.  Can you add the precise build problems that you are getting?  Which plugins are missing configurators?  You could try clicking the "ignore" quickfix for each of them.

Comment: I can, but they're the same ones that have been discussed in many other threads relating to Groovy and Maven in vanilla Eclipse, and I've been through all the troubleshooting I can to address them.  I have currently just ignored those build actions, and use the command line when I need to run them.  I was just hoping that STS could provide a better experience - we're using Gradle for our next project so everything should be rosy!  I've accepted your answer though Andrew, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you haven't figured this out completely, send a message here: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite Be sure to include all of the lifecycle mappings errors that you are receiving.  It is a matter of tracking down all the missing components.